# What is mapped_type and key_type?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a piece of code which says

```
typedef std::map<std::string, size_t>   name_map_type;
typedef name_map_type::mapped_type  name_map_mt;
typedef name_map_type::key_type     name_map_kt;
```

I am unable to figure out what exactly `mapped_type` and `key_type` means? Does `key_type` relate to the data type of key, which is `string` here and `mapped_type` relate to `size_t` or is it something else?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Comment: There is no "magic" here, mapped_type and key_type are just members of `std::map<>` like described in the link above. With a `std::map<std::string, size_t>`, mapped_type is `std::string` and `key_type` is `size_t`.

Comment: @deviantfan - It's the other way around for this example. A `name_map_type` (`std::map(std::string,size_t>`) has keys of type `std::string` (so that's the `name_map_type::key_type`) and values of type `size_t` (so that's the `name_map_type::mapped_type`).

Comment: @DavidHammen Whoops, right, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining type aliases. That is, you are saying that from now on `name_map_type` is an alias for `std::map<std::string, size_t>`. The same holds for `name_map_mt` and `name_map_kt`, which will act as aliases for the member types `std::map<std::string, size_t>::mapped_type` and `std::map<std::string, size_t>::key_type`, respectively.

Notice that such member types are aliases themselves, and are defined within the `std::map<K, V>` class definition. In particular, given a `std::map<K, V>`, we have that `std::map<K, V>::mapped_type` will be the same as `V`, whereas `std::map<K, V>::key_type` will be the same as `K`.